# How to compare a char to NULL without showing a warning?

Tags: c

I tried to compare command[8] with NULL, but it shows a warning cause NULL is void* type. Could someone tell me how to avoid that? Thank you in advance!

[image: The warning is like this]

Comment: `How to compare a char to NULL without showing a warning?` You just don't. Compare it to `0` or `'\0'` instead.

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you [don’t post screenshots or photos](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` is a macro for a null pointer constant. It is not for a null character.

To compare to a null character, use `'\0'`, as in `command[8] == '\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `NULL`
Try to use `'\0'` which is the null character symbol.

Comment: Yes  absolutely right.